# Hide dynamic nth number of table rows Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to hide table rows but it's not working. It is hiding the rows one by one like if I clicked first tr where class ‘plevel1’, its close tr class ”plevel2”. But when I am clicking like top parent level in this example (tr class plevel), it is only closing first tr class plevel1.

I need when I click the top class it will close all tr class plevel1 and their Childs. I am getting all levels and class name from the database. I have looked online the tr:nth-child but not sure how to implement this in my scenario. Also, I am new in JQuery. I prefer to use JQuery but if anyone has better idea, than I can use any language.

Please see the example below –

```
<table id = “tbl1”>
    <tr class=”plevel”>
        <td>
            <a class=”plevel1” onclick=”showhide(‘plevel1’)>Parent 1</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr class=”plevel1”>
        <td>
            <a class=”plevel2” onclick=”showhide(‘plevel2’)>Sub Parent 1</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr class=”plevel2” >
        <td>
            Sub Parent 1 child
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr class=”plevel1”>
        <td>
            <a class=”plevel3” onclick=”showhide(‘plevel3’)>Sub Parent 1</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table 

function showhide(hid) { 
   var login = hid;
   if ($("tr[class=" + hid + "]").is(":hidden")) {
       $("tr[class=" + hid + "]").show();
   } else if ($("tr[class=" + hid + "]").is(":visible")) {
       $("tr[class=" + hid + "]").hide();                                      
   }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is not tabular data, so using a `<table>` element is not appropriate. Its hierarchical data, so use `<ul>` or `<ol>` elements (or you could use nested `<div>` elements

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Level 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Level 1.1</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <span>Level 1.1.1</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>Level 1.1.2</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Level 1.2</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <span>Level 1.2.1</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And then to toggle the visibility of each items child elements, use the `.next()` selector

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
})
```

Refer [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rLs2r0u9/) for working example.

Comment: Great Stephen, this is exactly what I am looking for, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this not function in jquery

```js
function showhide(hid) { 
  $('table tr').not ("."+hid).hide();  
$("tr[class=" + hid + "]").show();  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id ="tbl1" border="1">
    <tr class="plevel">
        <td>
            <a class="plevel1" onclick="showhide('plevel1')">Parent 1</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr class="plevel1">
        <td>
            <a class="plevel2" onclick="showhide('plevel2')">Parent 2</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr class="plevel2">
        <td>
            Parent2 child
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr class="plevel1">
        <td>
            <a class="plevel3" onclick="showhide('plevel3')">Parent 3</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it is hiding everything, when clicking the link

Comment: When I click the top class in this example, it will close class plevel2 but will show all plevel1 classes.

Comment: $('#tbl1').not($("tr[class=" + hid + "]")).hide();  
          $("tr[class=" + hid + "]").show(); Use this code  first hide class then show class

Comment: Sorry, I am getting the same result

Comment: I will give you another query wait

Comment: Hi Rinto, sorry still it is hiding everything from the table, I am edited the table in my example for better understanding, please have a look, thanks

Comment: please check code snippet click above blue button Its working

Comment: When I clicked the Parent1, it will show Parent1, Parent2, Parent3, only needed to hide Parent2 child. When clicked Parent2, it will give me the same result. Because this is an example, in my table I have hundreds of rows under the Parent1, Parent2. Please check my updated table above, it will give you more clear picture, thanks